# Segmentation fault in recursive function, while parsing directories

Tags: c, file, recursion, directory

I am trying to make a program that returns the total size of a directory. The program takes the path to the directory, parses it, if it finds a file(done using a function) it adds the size, else
I recall the function. After some debugging i found out that the line containing the call to the recursive function give a segmentation fault and i have absolutely no idea how to fix it.

my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

int isDirectory(const char* fileName) {
    DIR* dir=opendir(fileName);
    if(dir!=NULL) {
        closedir(dir);
        return 1;
    } else if(errno == ENOTDIR) {
        return 0;
    } else return -1;
    closedir(dir);
}

int getFileSize(char* fileName) {
    FILE* file;
    file=fopen(fileName,"r");
    fseek(file,0,SEEK_END);
    int size=ftell(file);
    fclose(file);
    return size;
}

int getAllSize(char* dirName) {
    DIR* dir;
    char* name=dirName;
    int size=0;
    struct dirent *dent;
    dir=opendir(dirName);
    if(dir!=NULL) {
        while((dent=readdir(dir))!=NULL) {
            char help[1000000];
            memset(help,0,sizeof help);
            if(strcmp(dent->d_name,"..") && strcmp(dent->d_name,".")) {
            strcat(help,name);
            strcat(help,"/");
            strcat(help,dent->d_name);
            
            printf("%s\n",help);
            if(isDirectory(help)==1) {
                     getAllSize(name);
                } else{
                    printf("before %d\n",size);
                    size+=getFileSize(help);
                    printf("after %d\n",size);
                }    
            }
        }
    } else {
        printf("sal1\n");
    }
    closedir(dir);
    printf("%d",size);
    return size;
}

int main(int argc,char** argv) {
    getAllSize("/home/rares/Documents/OS/Lab3");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This statement closedir(dir); in teh function isDirectory never gets the control,

Comment: You probably get a stack overflow - heck, why do you allocate a local 1,000,000 byte buffer for the path name?

Comment: I found out that the reason I got the segmentation fault was because i was trying to recall that function with the wrong name(a variable that never changed), thus trying to reopen the same directory directory endlessly...kind of embarrassing that I didn't see I wasn't using the variable created specifically for that purpose.